# »Passt das dir?« oder »Passt dir das?«?

Tags: word-order, interrogative

Welcher Satz ist richtig?
Ich glaube, der erste, weil **das** das Subjekt ist

```
Passt das dir?
```

oder

```
Passt dir das?
```

Comment: `Passt dir das?` ist die gebräuchliche Variante. Warum aber in diesem Beispiel Dativobjekt vor Subjekt steht, kann ich nicht erklären, ich bin gespannt auf die Antworten.

Comment: "Probier mal das Kleid an. Passt das dir?" -- "Ich würde gerne morgen um acht vorbeikommen. Passt dir das?" Letzteres Beispiel könnte auch "Passt das dir?" verwenden. Ersteres geht allerdings nur so, nach meinem Gefühl.

Comment: @Deve vielleicht hat das was mit "Willst du das?" zu tun, was ja sicher richtig ist. Grammatikalisch sind die beiden Sätze nicht gleich, aber ihre inhaltliche Ähnlichkeit legt einen gleichen Satzbau nahe...

Comment: Die Satzgliedreihenfolge ist bis auf das Verb an 1. Stelle grammatikalisch egal. Die Reihenfolge kann aber eine Bedeutung vermitteln und hat ist dann semantisch nicht mehr egal. (Siehe Antwort von @Takkat)

Answer (score 6):

Wie immer ist auch hier der Kontext entscheidend. Beide Varianten sind richtig, können aber eine leicht verschiedene Betonung haben. Das kann man anhand von Beispielen gut sehen:

#### Passt dir das?

> - "Wir treffen uns am Samstag um vier Uhr bei Peter. Passt dir das?" – "Ja, mir passt das gut."
> - "Das Kleid hat Größe 36. Passt dir das?" – "Nein, ich trage Größe 38."

In diesen Beispielen betont die Frage die Sache (es könnte sich um eine andere Uhrzeit oder um eine andere Kleidergröße handeln).

#### Passt das dir?

> - "Hans, Eva und Bert haben für Samstag abgesagt, alle anderen können aber kommen. Passt das **dir**?" – "Ja, das passt mir."
> - "Das Kleid ist mir viel zu klein. Passt das **dir**?" – "Nein, mir passt das auch nicht."

In diesen Beispielen wird die Betonung auf die gefragte Person gelegt (die Uhrzeit könnte auch dem Gefragten nicht passen, oder das Kleid passt anderen Personen, aber nicht der Gefragten).

Comment: Sehe ich nicht so. Aber je länger und genauer ich hinschaue, desto mehr verschwimmen die Unterschiede und Erklärungen. Genaueren Aufschluss bringt wohl erst eine Frequenzanalyse.

Comment: Es sind nur Nuancen, die die beiden Varianten meist  austauschbar machen (vor allem wenn man noch eine andere Betonung berücksichtigt).

Comment: Bei dem Kleid würde ich „Passt es Dir?“ vorziehen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: in der Tat ist *"es"* hier die bevorzugte Variante. Das wäre übrigens auch eine gute Frage für hier, sofern es die nicht schon gibt. ;)