# "Sagt dir das etwas?" — warum steht das Dativobjekt vor dem Subjekt?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, dative, question

Normalerweise steht das Subjekt in Ja/Nein-Fragen an zweiter Stelle, sofort nach dem Verb.

> Hast du einen Wagen?

Aber im folgenden Satz kommt das Objekt vor das Subjekt:

> Sagt dir das etwas?

Ich verstehe nicht, warum es so geht, aber es wird häufig gebraucht. Es gibt auch andere Beispiele, wie in dieser Frage von Joe: [»Passt das dir?« oder »Passt dir das?«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/passt-das-dir-oder-passt-dir-das) (noch nicht geantwortet).

Meine Frage ist, ob es irgendwelche Regel gibt, die solche Wortstellung in meinem Beispiel reguliert? Gibt's noch andere Situationen, wo das Dativobjekt vor dem Subjekt steht? Wie kann das erklärt werden?

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Pronomen.xml?lang=de#id=3.5.3.2.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie an anderer Stelle erwähnt gibt es diese Wackernagel-Regel. Die bezieht sich jedoch auf das Indogermanische im Allgemeinen. Wie sie sich im Detail im Deutschen auswirkt, überblicke ich nicht. Kurz und vergröbernd gesagt treten kurze und unbetonte Pronomen immer möglichst weit vorne **an** die linke Satzklammer, jedoch **nicht vor** die linke Satzklammer. Linke Satzklammer ist normalerweise das konjugierte / finite Verb, in den angefragten Sätzen (als Verb-Erstsätzen) also *Hast* bzw. *Sagt*. Die kurzen und unbetonten Pronomen folgen unmittelbar auf dieses Verb, **egal, welche syntaktische Funktion (Subjekt, Objekt ...) sie haben!**

Beispiele dazu finden sich etwa in der Duden-Grammatik. In der Ausgabe 2016 heißt es dazu unter Randziffer 364 auf Seite 269:

> Betonte Pronomen können an denselben Stellen stehen wie entsprechende Satzglieder mit Substantiven; unbetonte Pronomen besetzen besondere Stellen (im Deutschen insbesondere die sogenannte Wackernagelposition; siehe dazu eingehend ↑ 1356–1360):
> Betont: *Dort kommt Anna. Ich will den Gästen auch **sie** noch vorstellen.* (Vgl.: *Ich will den Gästen auch **Anna** noch vorstellen.*)
> Unbetont: ?*Ich will den Gästen sie noch vorstellen.* (Stattdessen üblicherweise: *Ich will sie den Gästen noch vorstellen.*)

Und unter dem Verweis auf Randziffer 1356 ff. lesen wir:

> **2.3.2.3 Schwach betonte Pronomen**
>
> Für schwach betonte Pronomen gelten besondere Regeln:
>
> Tendenz: Schwach betonte Personal- und Reflexivpronomen stehen unmittelbar nach der linken Satzklammer.
>
> (...) Die spezielle Position für schwach betonte Pronomen wird nach dem Sprachhistoriker, der die Erscheinung als Erster exakt beschrieben hat, auch Wackernagelposition genannt.
> Die Regel, dass schwach betonte Pronomen diese Stelle einnehmen, ist im Deutschen relativ strikt (Lenerz 1977). Die folgenden Beispiele zeigen, dass Pronomen – unabhängig davon, was für eine Satzgliedfunktion sie haben – unmittelbar nach dem finiten Verb stehen:
>
> - *[Morgen] will [Anna] [der Chefin] [den Bericht] übergeben.*
> - → *[Morgen] will [sie] [der Chefin] [den Bericht] übergeben.*
> - → *[Morgen] will [ihr] [Anna] [den Bericht] übergeben.*
> - → *[Morgen] will [ihn] [Anna] [der Chefin] übergeben.*
>
> Einzig Subjekte können [!] noch vor den schwach betonten Pronomen stehen, nicht aber andere Satzglieder:
>
> - *[Morgen] will [Anna] [ihr] [den Bericht] übergeben.*
> - *[Morgen] will [Anna] [ihn] [der Chefin] übergeben.*
> - **[Morgen] will [den Bericht] [sie] [der Chefin] übergeben.*
> - **[Morgen] will [der Chefin] [sie] [den Bericht] übergeben.*
>
> Siehe dazu auch die folgenden Beispiele, bei denen die linke Satzklammer von einer Subjunktion besetzt ist. In (a) und (b) ist [die Kinder] Subjekt, während [den Kindern] in (c) und (d) Dativobjekt ist:
>
> - (a) *... weil [es] [die Kinder] lieben.*
> - (b) *... weil [die Kinder] [es] lieben.*
> - (c) *... weil [es] [den Kindern] gefällt.*
> - (d) **... weil [den Kindern] [es] gefällt*

Und da wir nun einmal dabei sind, sollte auch folgender Hinweis in der Duden-Grammatik auf Seite 881 (Randziffer 1357) beachtet werden:

> Wenn mehrere schwach betonte Pronomen in der Wackernagelposition stehen, gilt in der Standardsprache eine etwas andere Abfolge als für normale Nominalphrasen.
>
> Tendenz bei schwach betonten Pronomen: Subjekt > Akkusativobjekt > Dativobjekt (> da)
>
> Auffällig ist, dass hier entgegen der sonstigen Tendenz (↑ 1353) Pronomen im Akkusativ vor solchen im Dativ stehen:
>
> - *[Anna] will [der Chefin] [den Bericht] [morgen] übergeben.*
> - → **[Anna] will [ihr] [ihn] [morgen] übergeben.*
> - → *[Anna] will [ihn] [ihr] [morgen] übergeben.*

Allerdings (!):

> In regionalen Varietäten des Deutschen gilt zum Teil die umgekehrte Abfolge Dativ > Akkusativ. Das Pronomen es, zumal in der Kurzform s oder’s, kann aber auch standardsprachlich nach einem Dativ-Pronomen stehen:
>
> - *... weil [Otto] [seinem Kollegen] [das korrekte Vorgehen] gezeigt hat.*
> - *... weil [Otto] [es] [ihm] gezeigt hat.*
> - *... weil [Otto] [ihm] [es] gezeigt hat.*
> - *... weil [Otto] [ihm] [’s] gezeigt hat.*

Hinzu kommt folgendes: In meinem Dialektraum (Ruhrgebiet) werden in der gesprochenen Sprache die 'normalen' "Personal"pronomen (die sich in der dritten Person aber meist nicht auf Personen beziehen) wegen ihrer schwachen Betonung fast durchgängig durch die sogenannten 'Demonstrativpronomen' *der, die, das, den, dem, denen ...* ersetzt. Diese gelten dann nicht als 'schwach betont', für sie gelten andere Stellungsregeln:

- *Er hat [mir] [das] schön erklärt*

aber nicht

- **Er hat [das] [mir] schön erklärt*

wohl aber, siehe oben

- *Er hat [es] [mir] schön erklärt.*

Comment: Sie haben mir das schön erklärt! Vielen Dank:-)

Comment: Die Antwort ist sehr umfangreich, aber warum *dir das* besser klingt als *das dir* in *Sagt … etwas?*, wird nicht erklärt (es sei denn, ich habe etwas überlesen).

Comment: Meine Frage war nicht, warum es besser klingt — ich wollte vor allem wissen, ob es überhaupt grammatisch korrekt ist. Aber in dieser Antwort gibt's eigentlich eine Erklärung: weil das Pronomen "das" betont wird, steht es nach dem unbetonten Dativobjekt.

Comment: Die andere Sache ist, dass "das" (und andere Demonstrativpronomen), laut Ralf, gewöhnlich (mindestens in Ruhrgebiet) immer nach dem Dativobjekt steht.

Comment: @ALÖ - Zur letzten Antwort: Diese Spezialregel gilt nur, wenn die als betont geltenden Demonstrativa akkusativisch sind. Als Nominativa können Sie nach den Duden-Regeln sehr wohl den Dativpronomen vorangehen (siehe oben "Einzig Subjekte ..."): _Warum sagst du ihr nicht einfach, was los ist? - Weil **die mir** auch nichts erzählt._ Ein solcher auf Personen bezogener Gebrauch von sogenannten Demonstrativa gilt je nach sozialer Zugehörigkeit als salopp, wenn nicht abwertend, zumindest im Regelbewusstsein, entgegen dem ständigen Sprachgebrauch - sind halt Regeln, damit hat sich's dann aber auch.

Comment: Ja, ich sehe auch so. Also ein bisschen wie mit bestimmten Artikeln vor den Namen, richtig? "Wo ist der Peter?" — klingt es auch salopp?

Comment: @ALÖ Für mich wäre "der Peter" eher familiär. Das mit den 'Demonstrativa' für Personen ist eine heikle Sache. Als Kindern wurde uns beigebracht, nicht z.B. auf die Peter-Frage zu antworten "_Der ist zum Arzt gegangen_", vor allem, wenn von Erwachsenen die Rede war - das galt als respektlos, so, als wenn man mit dem Zeigefingern auf die Person zeigen würde. (Dafür gab's einen extra Spruch: _Man zeigt nicht mit nacktem Finger auf angezogene Leute._) Der Spruch für _**Der** ist nicht da_ war: _**Der** steht auf'em Markt und verkauft Äppel!_, was so viel bedeuten sollte wie: ...

Comment: ... So darf man nur über einfache Leute sprechen, wenn überhaupt - bzw.: So sollte man überhaupt nicht über andere Leute reden. Ich weiß nicht mehr, ob sich die Erwachsenen auch daran gehalten hatten, jedenfalls reden heute in der Umgangssprache meiner Region alle so. Aber geschrieben werden nur die 'guten' Pronomen "er / sie / ihn / ihm / ihr", es sei denn, man schreibt in Umgangssprache, was ich z.B. ziemlich oft tue. Für mich sind diese 'Demonstrativa' eigentlich bloß betonte Personalpronomen, die gibt's ja in anderen Sprachen auch, z.B. Frz. _lui (il)_ statt _il_ usw. ...

Comment: ... Also in normalem Umgangsdeutsch: _Maria? Die hab' ich vorhin in der Stadt gesehen._ Und in etwas steifem Standarddeutsch: _Maria? Ich hab(e) sie vorhin in der Stadt gesehen._ Bezogen auf die Ausgangsfrage: Umgangssprachlich = _Hast du ihr / der auch gesagt, wo sie den Schlüssel abgeben soll? - Jaa doch, ich hab der das dreimal erklärt!_ Standarddeutsch geht beides nur mit _ihr_ .

Comment: Vielen Dank! Sehr hilfreich.